# Arduino + Android USB alarm

Tags: java, android, arduino, usb

I'm trying to make an alarm for my Arduino uno 3.
I wrote an application for Android and Arduino.

Arduino code

```
const int przycisk = 2;    
int buttonState = 0;      
int wtes = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);  
    pinMode(przycisk, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(przycisk);

  if(buttonState==LOW){ 
     wtes=0;
  }

  if(buttonState==HIGH && wtes == 0) {
     Serial.print("TAK");  
     wtes=1;
  } 
}
```

Android java

```
UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { // Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                final CharSequence ftext = data;

                if (ftext.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("TAK")) {
                    String numer = "00000000000"; //
                    String smswiad = "masssage";

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(numer, null, smswiad, null, null);
                }
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

When I press the button, Arduino sends "TAK" to the smartphone and then Android sends an SMS.

It's sending the SMS when I push the button, but not always.
Why so?

Comment: I mean its not always send sms when i push button. Sorry for my english its not my native language

Comment: So you say that TAK is received but hat the sms is not sent? Is here a catch then?

Comment: Its random 1/3 sms is not sent. I know on 100% all TAK is received.

Comment: Just do a test on your Android device sending sms' now and then. Use a timer to schedule. Check if all arrive. `String numer = "00000000000"; `. Increment that numer every time.